# can i move the installed android sdk from XP system to windows7 ? Is it possible?

Tags: android

i installed complete android package in XP system, i have windows7 in another pc but I dont want to do installing new software again . can i move it to Windows7 easily ?if possible what is the procedure?

Comment: Could you give more details on how you went about doing this please? I have the same situation at the moment and don't work with Android SDK every day.

Comment: @SixfootJames you just need to copy android sdk folder and eclipse and set the preference in eclipse for your new location.. thats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works . for that you just need to copy your android-sdk folder from where it installed and set necessary path in environment variables .

Comment: Hi Chiraq. What do you mean " and set necessary path in environment variables" Where would one do this? Thanks

Comment: Suppose in that xp system your sdk folder is in E Drive and in Widows 7 if you put this sdk folder in D drive then you need to set that sdk folder path in environmnet variable .